# Asp.net web api get post data in action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter, postdata

I post the json data to the web api action,
I defined a customer action filter for the gloabl action filter,
but how can i get the post data in the action filter?

Comment: May we see the code, please?